# GoogleTv android EMulator on Ubuntu

Tags: android, google-tv, kvm

I recently tried to get GoogleTv android emulator running on my Ubuntu 12 Desktop edition (KVM enabled).
Upon start up, the screen goes blank.
I checked the log file with debug-all option and this is what I got :
Then on the last 2 lines repeats over and over.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Deepak

```
 *deepak@DeepakUbuntu:~$ sudo Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd GoogleTV -debug-all
[sudo] password for deepak: 
emulator: found SDK root at /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.ini
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='target' VALUE='Google Inc.:Google TV Addon:12'
emulator:    2: KEY='path' VALUE='/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd'
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.ini: parsing finished
emulator: virtual device content at /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/config.ini
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/config.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='213'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='Emulator'
emulator:    3: KEY='sdcard.size' VALUE='1024M'
emulator:    4: KEY='skin.name' VALUE='720p'
emulator:    5: KEY='skin.path' VALUE='add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='x86'
emulator:    7: KEY='abi.type' VALUE='x86'
emulator:    8: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='256'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='1024'
emulator:   10: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='128'
emulator:   11: KEY='image.sysdir.1' VALUE='add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/'
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/config.ini: parsing finished
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found target field in root AVD .ini file: 'Google Inc.:Google TV Addon:12'
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 12
emulator:     found image search path: add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
emulator: found a total of 1 search paths for this AVD
emulator: found skin '720p' in directory: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 720p
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p/hardware.ini
emulator: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p/hardware.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    2: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='256'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='1024'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='213'
emulator:    5: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='128'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='Emulator'
emulator: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p/hardware.ini: parsing finished
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/deepak/.android/default.keyset
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='65'
emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='24'
emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1351869589780'
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/skins/720p/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: found kernel-qemu in search dir: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: found ramdisk.img in search dir: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: found system.img in search dir: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB
emulator:     no Emulator.kcm in search dir: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86/
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = Emulator
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1280
  hw.lcd.height = 720
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 213
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 256
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//ramdisk.img

  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 25m
  avd.name = GoogleTV
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-x86 -android-hw /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='x86'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='1024'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    5: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='no'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='no'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='Emulator'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard.path' VALUE='/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/sdcard.img'
emulator:   18: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition.path' VALUE='/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/cache.img'
emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
emulator:   21: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='1280'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='720'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='213'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   26: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
emulator:   27: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='emulated'
emulator:   28: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   29: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='256'
emulator:   30: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   31: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   34: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='/home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//kernel-qemu'
emulator:   35: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1'
emulator:   36: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='/home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//ramdisk.img'
emulator:   37: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='/home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//system.img'
emulator:   38: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='200m'
emulator:   39: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/userdata-qemu.img'
emulator:   40: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='25m'
emulator:   41: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='GoogleTV'
emulator: /home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=/home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12/images/x86//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-root/emulator-ouTTXo
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x1900000,file=/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 1902000
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '256m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '213'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 127.0.1.1
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/deepak/.android/avd/GoogleTV.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: KVM mode auto-enabled!
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/bios.bin
emulator:     trying to find: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin
emulator:     trying to find: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin
emulator:     trying to find: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin
emulator: qpa_audio_init: entering
emulator: qpa_audio_init: exiting
emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.870968
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Using config file: /home/deepak/.android/modem-nv-ram-5554
Setting value of oper_name_index to 2 (2)Setting value of selection_mode to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_index to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_count to 2 (2)Setting value of in_ecbm to 0 (0)Setting value of prl_version to 0 (0)Setting value of preferred_mode to 15 (15)Setting value of cdma_subscription_source to 1 (1)Setting value of cdma_roaming_pref to 2 (2)emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /home/deepak/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms ping emulator 20.0.3.0 "Intel Open Source Technology Center" "Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2" "2.1 Mesa 9.0"
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.
```

0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 27
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure your adb connection

https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_debug

After that, you can debug your program.

Answer (score 1):

Can you file an issue at http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/ and I will make sure it gets looked at.